# obtain user name from protected folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory, protected

I have a protected folder on my server with access to several users defined through cpanel.

Is there a way for PHP to tell me which user has logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is protected via HTTP authentication, then the username may be available in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`.  [More on the `$_SERVER[]` superglobal array...](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)